# Erro na consulta do CEP no PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, url, cep

Estou tentando corrigir no PHP a URL que consulta o CEP, ao digitar o CEP XXXXX-XXX a URL está apresentando os caracteres **amp;** que estão ocasionando erro no resultado do XML.

Consulta correta:

```
http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?formato=xml&cep=88160-282
```

Consulta com erro:

```
http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?formato=xml&amp;cep=88160-282
```

Como remover os caracteres amp; da consulta?

```
    // FUNÇAO PARA CONSULTAR CEP

public function consultarCep() {
    $cep = $_POST['cep'];

    $reg = simplexml_load_file("http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?formato=xml&cep=" . $cep);

    $dados['sucesso'] = (string) $reg->resultado;
    $dados['endereco'] = (string) $reg->tipo_logradouro . ' ' . $reg->logradouro;
    $dados['bairro'] = (string) $reg->bairro;
    $dados['cidade'] = (string) $reg->cidade;
    $dados['estado'] = (string) $reg->uf;

    echo json_encode($dados);
}
```

Comment: // FUNÇAO PARA CONSULTAR CEP
    
    public function consultarCep() {
        $cep = $_POST['cep'];

        $reg = simplexml_load_file("http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?formato=xml&cep=" . $cep);

        $dados['sucesso'] = (string) $reg->resultado;
        $dados['endereco'] = (string) $reg->tipo_logradouro . ' ' . $reg->logradouro;
        $dados['bairro'] = (string) $reg->bairro;
        $dados['cidade'] = (string) $reg->cidade;
        $dados['estado'] = (string) $reg->uf;

        echo json_encode($dados);
    }

Comment: Clique em [edit] para acrescentar na pergunta acima, e use o atalho Control K para formatar como código (ou use o botão `{ }` da barra de formatação)

Comment: Pergunta atualizada.

Comment: Não relacionado ao problema do &amp, mas não é melhor pegar em JSON mesmo?

Comment: Vou tentar mudar a consultar. Obrigado!

Comment: O simplexml_load_file faz umas maluquices mesmo no escape (antes da versão 5.1 do PHP era diferente, e depende da versão da LibXml). De qq forma, o JSON é muito mais simples pro PHP, e vocè pode pegar a string com operação de arquivo, com curl, tem muitas maneiras (por exemplo, `$json = file_get_contents( caminho ); $data = json_decode($json, true);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `html_entity_decode`.

**Exemplo:**

```
$var = "http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?formato=xml&amp;cep=88160-282";

echo html_entity_decode($var);
```

Comment: Essa é a resposta da sua pergunta, porém acho que isso não resolve o erro no resultado do XML, se o erro persistir faça outra pergunta exibindo o erro.